# Native query not working for write ,delete and update operation

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am new to springboot and facing issue in JPQL,nativeQuery. While doing read operation native query is working

```
@Query(value="select * from student s where s.name= :name", nativeQuery=true)
List<Student> getStudentByName(String name);
```

working but its not working when doing delete operation on database

```
    @Query(value="delete from student s where s.name= :name",nativeQuery = true)
    void deleteStudentByName(String name);
```

Entity Class

```
    package com.example.demo.test.entity;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    
    @Entity
    public class Student {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;
        private String name;
        private Integer age;
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public Integer getAge() {
            return age;
        }
        public void setAge(Integer age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
    
    }
```

Please help. Thank you

Comment: Can you show the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write operations need to be executed differently than read operations, you also need to annotate the repository method with a @Modifying annotation. Hence put @Modifying above the delete Query.

```
@Modifying
@Query(value="delete from student s where s.name= :name",nativeQuery = true) 
void deleteStudentByName(String name);
```

I suggest you to not write nativeQuery and learn JPQL because

1. Pagination of native query results requires an extra step.
2. Spring Data JPA doesn’t support dynamic sorting for native SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use the JPQL Query like void deleteByName(String name);

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use this code inside your repo

```
   @Modifying
   @Transactional
   @Query(value="delete from student s where s.name= ?1",nativeQuery = true)
   void deleteStudentByName(String name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query

```
@Query("DELETE FROM Student c WHERE c.name = ?1")
    void deleteStudentByName(String name);
```

And I suggest you learn how to write  JPQL queries: https://www.javatpoint.com/jpa-jpql-introduction